# SQL -joining two table or generating the sequence in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, Table1 got OrderNo and OrderItemId, Table2 got OrderNo and Linenum. I need to make temporary table which shows orderno, orderItemid and Linenum. How can I achieve the desired result.
If joining is not possible then we can generate the sequence also for number of OrderItemId against a Order. Suppose Order got 5 OrderItemId then we can have series from 1 to 5 and next order will have series starting from 1 up to total number of Orderitemid associated.

I tried this, but series is not generating correctly . Its not order wise

```
Select Orderitemid, table1.OrderNo,  
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table2.ORDERNO ASC)*1000 AS Linenum 
from Table1 inner join Table2
on table1.Orderno = table2.Orderno
```

[image]

Comment: In The Table1, and table 2 , if we add price column and want to display along with other column. Just wanted make sure order price in both the table are matching. Any suggestion for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would be what you are looking for:

```
select table1.OrderNo
       , table1.Orderitemid
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by table1.OrderNo ORDER BY table1.ORDERNO ASC) AS Linenum 
from Table1 
left join Table2 on table1.OrderNo = table2.OrderNo
group by table1.OrderNo, table1.Orderitemid
```

You can do the group by only for table2:

```
select table1.OrderNo
       , table1.Orderitemid
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by table1.OrderNo ORDER BY table1.ORDERNO ASC) AS Linenum 
from Table1 
left join (select OrderNo 
           from Table2 
           group by OrderNo) table2 on table1.OrderNo = table2.OrderNo
```

Or just use distinct:

```
select table1.OrderNo
       , table1.Orderitemid
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by table1.OrderNo ORDER BY table1.ORDERNO ASC) AS Linenum 
from Table1 
left join (select distinct OrderNo 
           from Table2 ) table2 on table1.OrderNo = table2.OrderNo
```

Or if you do not want to generate Linenum if there is no connection in table2 then you can add `case when then else end`

```
select table1.OrderNo
       , table1.Orderitemid
       , case when table2.OrderNo is not null then
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by table1.OrderNo ORDER BY table1.ORDERNO ASC)
              else
                  null
              end Linenum
from Table1 
left join (select distinct OrderNo 
           from Table2 ) table2 on table1.OrderNo = table2.OrderNo
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23664c97ec8391b577dc93faa48fc2a7)

Comment: You are welcome, I am happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: The Only issue , now if the Orderno is not in table 2 then it should not generate the sequence. But it is . If I use case as suggested by Gordon then group by gives error

Comment: You do not want to have results for 3000 in your example ?

Comment: @Sbanga please check the last query here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5114069e026da3303b1ef9b500f2b891

Comment: Hi @Sbanga Why was this now marked as not correct answer ?

Comment: I am sorry Its by mistake, i open the page to write some more query

Comment: In The Table1, and table 2 , if we add price column and want to display along with other column. Just wanted make sure order price in both the table are matching. Any suggestion for that.

Comment: Hello @Sbanga the best thing you can do is to open a new question and add details just like this (including the price...). A lot of people will see new question and will help you faster. Do not forget to add example data and expexted results in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a `case` expression:

```
Select Orderitemid, table1.OrderNo,
       (case when t2 is not null
             then row_number() over (partition by t1.orderno order by t1.orderitemid)
        end) as linenum
from Table1 t1 left join
     (select distinct t2.orderno
      from Table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.Orderno = t2.Orderno;
```

That is, you just want the row numbers when there is a match in the second table.

Comment: Its giving me result in  Cristian . Where it should only show 2 rows, but its showing 4                                                                                                    OrderNo OrderItemId LineNum
1000 101 1
1000 101 2
1000 102 1
1000 102 2

Comment: @Sbanga . . . I missed that you have duplicates in the second table.  I updated the answer.